# No module named simpy

Tags: python

He instalado ***SimPy*** usando el comando `pip install -U simpy` tal y como lo pone esta página https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simpy pero al tratar de importarlo como `import simpy` me da el error del título:

> ImportError: No module named 'simpy'

He instalado *NumPy*, *Matplotlib* y otras librerías de la misma forma y no me han dado este problema, ¿alguien sabe a que se deba?. Estoy usando el Python 3.6.0

Comment: Pon en la terminal `pip freeze` y obtendrás el nombre y la versión de todos los paquetes instalados, mira a vr si existe simpy, creo que la última versión es `simpy 3.0.10`. Si no está no se instalo por algo. Te recomiendo lanzar siempre pip como módulo, para instalar simpy en python 3.6 (por si tienes más versiones) en Windows : `py -3.6 -m pip install simpy`. Mira a ver si te marca algún error, también puedes instalarlo usando un binario descargandolo desde [aquí](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) y usando  `py -3.6 -m pip install nobredelarchivo.whl`

Comment: @FJSevilla mira que usando el pip freeze veo que si esta en la lista simpy 3.0.10 pero igual da el error de que no se encuentra el modulo. No tengo mas versiones de python pero igual voy a intentar lo que me has sugerido, gracias :)

Comment: @FJSevilla haciendo lo de py -3.6 -m pip install simpy si funciona man muchas gracias :3

Comment: @FJSevilla tengo python(x,y) tambien instalado crees que sea por eso que no lo haya puesto en python 3.6 antes? porque creo que python (x,y) trabaja con python 2.7 y talves le haya dado prioridad, sino nose porque no funciono antes el pip install -U simpy

Comment: He creado una respuesta extendiendo el comentario anterior, explicandolo todo un poco mejor ya que sabemos cual era el problema por si le sirve a alguien más. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar `py -3.6 -m pip freeze` en la terminal para  obtener el nombre y la versión de todos los paquetes instalados, mira a ver si existe SimPy entre ellos. Si no está no se instalo por algo, si no dio errores posiblemente tengas varias versiones de Python instalados en tu sistema operativo y se instaló en otra.

Cuando en se tienen varias versiones de Python instaladas en el mismo sistema operativo si al lanzar `pip` en la terminal no especificas la versión en la que deseas instalar el paquete pip se ejecuta por defecto en la versión que usa el sistema de forma predeterminada para ejecutar módulos Python y es en esta versión en la que se instala el módulo. Para saber que versión tienes definida como predeterminada basta con poner en la terminal `python` o `py` y se te iniciara el intérprete donde podrás ver la versión.

Para especificarlo basta con llamar al interprete correspondiente y usar `pip` como un módulo cualquiera junto al uso de [Python Launcher](http://blog.python.org/2011/07/python-launcher-for-windows_11.html) en plataformas **Windows**:

`py -3.6 -m pip install simpy` Instala SimPy en Python 3.6
`py -3.5 -m pip install simpy` Instala SimPy en Python 3.5
`py -2.7 -m pip install simpy` Instala SimPy en Python 2.7

Siempre es recomendable lanzar `pip` como módulo (`-m`) aunque solo se tenga una versión instalada de Python.

Comment: Muy bueno man, lo unico que tambien hubiese sido util que incluyeras es como cambiar el python predeterminado, el mio tiene por defecto por lo que veo el 2.7, hay manera de cambiarlo a 3.6 u otra version? Muchas gracias :)